# IE9 confirm browser exit

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

There is a lot of questions on stackoverflow.com about this issue. But there is really no answer, or I couldn't find it (in that case, I am sorry for this duplicate).

So I have an Ajax based web application, and I want to know if user want's to leave the page. Here's a snippet what I have:

```
function goodbye(e) {
    if(!stopGoodbye) {
        if(!e) e = window.event;
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        e.returnValue = 'You are leaving the system!'; 
        if (e.stopPropagation) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    } 
}
window.onbeforeunload=goodbye
```

`stopgoodbye` is for turning off when clicking logout.

This works in Firefox, but in IE9 it is showing the dialog everytime user clicks a link which just changes some DIV content (an Ajax link)... If it helps, I am using Struts2 framework with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

you can actually turn the onbeforeupload warning off for the user(when they clicked on a link) by adding an onclick event to the anchor.

you can read more about [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the solution are in the comments

Comment: Hm, that would mean that I would have to change all the links in the application... I hope there's another solution :)

Comment: another solution would be to check for the user agent and if the clicked event comes from an anchor in your goodbye function. You can then stop the warning from coming out.